# Filter on the_content doesn't update the content being searched via register_rest_route

Tags: filters, tags, rest-api, the-content

I'm trying to get my custom REST route to include search results from a filtered `the_content`. I'm trying to automatically include the post tag names within each post's content, so that searching can be performed on the post tags without the need to copy and paste the tags into each post's content. My content filter successfully returns the tags on each page like I want:

```
    // Customise the_content
    function wpa_content_filter( $content ) {

        $post_tags = get_the_tags();

        if ( $post_tags ) {
            $tags = get_the_tags();
            $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
            foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
                $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

                $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
                $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
            }
            $html .= '</div>';
            echo $html;
            $newContent = $content.$html;
        } else {
            $newContent = $content;
        }

        return $newContent;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpa_content_filter' );
```

But my REST API doesn't return the same filtered content:

```
"content": "<!-- wp:paragraph -->\n<p>Scarborough Marsh is located southwest of Portland, Maine.</p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->"
```

(This should be displaying the tags as well, like it is on the page.)

Here's my register_rest_route:

```
 
    add_action ('rest_api_init', 'somRegisterSearch');

    function somRegisterSearch() {
        register_rest_route('customapi/v1', 'search', array(
            'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
            'callback' => 'somSearchResults'
        ));
    }

    function somSearchResults($data) {

        $places = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            's' => sanitize_text_field($data['term']),

        ));
        $placesResults = array();

        while ($places->have_posts()) {
            $places->the_post();
            
            array_push($placesResults, array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'thumbnail'),
                'content' => get_the_content(),
                // 'terms' => get_terms( array(
                //     'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                //     'hide_empty' => false,
                // ) )
            ));
        }

        return $placesResults;
    }
```

Comment: The `the_content` filter is not applied to `get_the_content()`. You would need to use `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )`. But even if you did that, any content you added is not going to be searchable. That's not how it works, whether or not you use the REST API.

Comment: So there's no way to make customized the_content searchable?

Comment: @DavidMerritt Did you ever find a way for this?